# SQL Server 2008 query - to find the emails that are not presents in two different colums in different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not able to solve this issue, can you help me?

I have a table `dbo.Users` --> in this table I have an `Email` column and inside many emails

and

I have another table `dbo.aspnet_Membership` --> in this table I have `Email` column and inside many emails

And I would to extract only the `Emails` that are not in both the columns.

For example:

tab1 col1 :

```
111@111.com
222@222.com
333@333.com
```

tab2 col2:

```
111@111.com
222@222.com
```

I would to extract (or delete) all `333@333.com` Emails.

Comment: what if the email is in table2 and not in table1?

Answer (score 4):

since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use the [**`EXCEPT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) set operator like so:

```
SELECT EMAIL FROM Table1
EXCEPT 
SELECT Email FROM table2
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9049d/1)

**Update:** This will give you all the emails that are in the `Table1` that are not present in the second table. However if you want to get all the emails that are not presented in the two tables(thanks to [**@gilly3**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361684/gilly3)), try this:

```
(
  SELECT EMAIL FROM Table1
  EXCEPT 
  SELECT Email FROM table2
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT EMAIL FROM Table2
  EXCEPT 
  SELECT Email FROM table1
)
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57642/7)

Comment: And, when `table2` contains `444@444.com` and you want to retrieve that email as well, union that query with the reverse of itself: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57642/7).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Users u FULL JOIN dbo.aspnet_Membership m ON u.Email = m.Email
WHERE u.Email IS NULL OR m.Email IS NULL
```

Demo on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c09be/6/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *
from dbo.Users
where email not in
(select email
from dbo.aspnet_Membership)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * From Users WHERE email NOT IN
(
  Select email From Users u
  JOIN aspnet_Membership m
     ON u.email = m.email
)



Select * From aspnet_Membership WHERE email NOT IN
(
  Select email From Users u
  JOIN aspnet_Membership m
     ON u.email = m.email
)
```

You can change the select statement to DELETE